# What does "in charge look" in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, phrase-meaning

A guy sent me this:

> I love your in charge look lol guys should bow to you.

I really don't get what he means especially that "in charge look " part, as English isn't my native language.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Was that okcupid? I just received a very, very similar one. It's either a thing, or it's clearly the same guy and his very confusing pick-up line.

Comment: Yeah!lol. That's awkward

Answer (score 2):

To be the person in charge means to be the person responsible for something or someone...the person may refer to an appearance which commands respect or authority ...to which people should bow ..

Answer (score 2):

He means that you look like you're in charge. You must have dressed smartly, or given off the appearance of being in command.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was an informal communication, but it might make more sense if it was written with some punctuation.

I love your "in charge" look. LOL.  Guys should bow to you.

He sounds like he's a bit on the submissive side.

Comment: Oh! That's awkward then.… omggggg! I just  freaked out